# How do I determine list type (ul/li vs span) using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working with a user-created table and list, where my program has to read in a list of entries for processing. I have the processors functioning, and I can navigate to the location in the table without any problems. The issue is that I am trying to allow for some flexibility in creating the list (inside the table) by allowing for the creator to input the list by either using un-ordered lists `(/ul/li)` and carriage-returns `(/p)`.

Right now, I am determining whether the un-ordered list is used via `driver.findElements(By.xpath("foo/ul/li")).size()` being greater than `0`. The issue is that this can take forever to "fail over." Is there a way that I am missing for making verifying element type `(/ul/li vs /p vs /ol/li)` faster?

I am using Java and Webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to check if the concerned list is ordered or unordered by getting the size() and checking if it is greater than "0".

**My suggestion is to get the parent tag of first "*li*" element which will then return "*ul*" or "*li*"**.
You can try the below code for that (**Assuming list is present under some 'div' tag**):

```
String tag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//li[1]/..")).getTagName();//Returns the parent tag of the first element in the list
if(tag.contains("ul"))
  System.out.println("List is unordered");
else if(tag.contains("li"))
  System.out.println("List is ordered.");
```